# Why are there unnecssary internal Tor browser pages?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox, settings

Tor browser has some internal pages inherited from Mozilla Firefox. These include: `about:privatebrowsing`, `about:webrtc`, `about:mozilla`, etc. Since the Tor browser already uses private browsing, does not support webRTC, and `about:mozilla` isn't really necessary, why does the Tor browser keep these pages? Is there a purpose/reason behind this or does the Tor browser just keep it for just the sake of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely answer is: **Tor Browser keeps these pages because there is no reason to remove them.**

Firefox is a big, complex project with lots of components that depend on each other. And it keeps changing, both to make it perform better and to keep up with changing Internet standards. It is not really possible to just pick the parts you want; you have to start with the whole project, then change the parts you want to change. Every change takes effort to create, effort to verify and effort to keep up to date every time Firefox changes. So Tor Browser does not change things without a good reason.

In fact, Mozilla has a [Tor Uplift project](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Tor_Uplift), which intends to move all Tor Browser patches into Firefox (controlled by preferences where appropriate), where they are more easily maintained.